# do triple track window panels have an inner frame

Tags: windows

Does a triple track glass storm window, with an aluminum frame, and a metal slide bolt;  always have the glass pane glazed into a second, separate, inner aluminum frame?

Are there certain brands or certain years where this is commonplace?

Given a window WITH an inner frame, is that inner frame typically mitre joined and the outer frame is always butt joined?